# Reverse cumsum with breaks with non-sequential numbers

Tags: r, seq, cumsum

Looking to fill a matrix with a reverse cumsum. There are multiple breaks that must be maintained.

I have provided a sample matrix for what I want to accomplish. The first column is the data, the second column is what I want. You will see that column 2 is updated to reflect the number of items that are left. When there are 0's the previous number must be carried through.

```
update <- matrix(c(rep(0,4),rep(1,2),2,rep(0,2),1,3, 
  rep(10,4), 9,8,6, rep(6,2), 5, 2),ncol=2)
```

I have tried multiple ways to create a sequence, loop using numerous packages (i.e. zoo). What is difficult is that the numbers in column 1 can be between 0,1,..,X but less than column 2.

Any help or tips would be appreciated

EDIT: Column 2 starts with a given value which can represent any starting value (i.e. inventory at the beginning of a month). Column 1 would then represent "purchases" made which; thus, column 2 should reflect the total number of remaining items available.

Comment: Can you explain why `update[1, 2]` is `10` ?

Comment: This would give you your desired result: `10 - cumsum(update[, 1])`

Comment: I have now edited the question to clarify your concern

Comment: See my second comment.

Comment: Thank you @markus. Was much simpler than I was making it. Up-voted your comment

Answer (score 0):

The following will report the purchase and inventory balance as described:

```
starting_inventory <- 100
df <- data.frame(purchases=c(rep(0,4),rep(1,2),2,rep(0,2),1,3))
df$cum_purchases <- cumsum(df$purchases)
df$remaining_inventory <- starting_inventory - df$cum_purchases
```

Result:

```
   purchases cum_purchases remaining_inventory
1          0             0                 100
2          0             0                 100
3          0             0                 100
4          0             0                 100
5          1             1                  99
6          1             2                  98
7          2             4                  96
8          0             4                  96
9          0             4                  96
10         1             5                  95
11         3             8                  92
```